# Convert a Collection<String> into comma sepearted values

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The most sophisticated way for creating comma-separated Strings from a Collection/Array/List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205555/the-most-sophisticated-way-for-creating-comma-separated-strings-from-a-collection)

I have a Collection

I wanted to have a String object from the Collection Object with elements as Comma seperated.

For eg

```
      Collection<String> = [1,2,3..]
      String temp = "1,2,3,4....";
```

Comment: You want something special other than simple iteration?

Comment: Iterate through collection and concatenate the result.

Comment: Iterate over the collection and append the elements with the seperator?

Comment: These are very basic questions which are best suited for Google or an introductory Java text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String getCsv(List<String> list) {
    if (list == null)
        return null;
    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
          String item = list[i];
          if (i!=0)
              buff.append(",");
          buff.append(item);
    }
    return buff.toString();
 }
```

Comment: this code should take care properly of first/last element and it is using StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer since it is faster by a small margin in non-concurrent code

Answer (score 0):

iterate over your collection and use a `StringBuilder` and append each element and a comma. if the collection has more then 0 elements, delete the last comma.

```
public static String getMyString(Collection<String> coll) { 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String str : coll) {
        sb.append(str).append(",");
    }

    if (coll.size() > 0) {
        sb.delete(sb.length()-1,sb.length());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: If it is last element, skip the comma. Or even you can remove the last comma after completing through the iteration.\

Comment: If it is not the first element put a comma in front of it.