# How to convert a List<String> into a comma separated string without iterating List explicitly

Tags: java, list

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
ids.add("1");
ids.add("2");
ids.add("3");
ids.add("4");
```

Now i want an output from this list as 1,2,3,4 without **explicitly** iterating over it.

Comment: Define "iterating it fully", because neither god, cthulu, nor the flying spaghetti monster could get the items out of the list without iterating over all of it in some manner.

Comment: Without iterating? :S how can your app get the content of each element without iterating??

Comment: I don't want to do like - String commaSepIds = ""; for(String text : ids){ commaSepIds = commaSepIds +","+ +text;}

Comment: Chuck Norris can do that.

Comment: Even Jack Bauer too...

Answer (score 498):

On Android use:

```
android.text.TextUtils.join(",", ids);
```

Comment: Damn, i wish i could upvote this a few times! Helped me several times!! :)

Comment: This answer is limited to ANDROID! Use the StringUtils answer below

Comment: TextUtils has so many hidden gems - Google should do a better job at promoting them... They also have other util classes that are awesome and not well known.

Answer (score 164):

With Java 8:

```
String csv = String.join(",", ids);
```

With Java 7-, there is a dirty way (***note: it works only if you don't insert strings which contain `", "` in your list***) - obviously, `List#toString` will perform a loop to create `idList` but it does not appear in your code:

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
ids.add("1");
ids.add("2");
ids.add("3");
ids.add("4");
String idList = ids.toString();
String csv = idList.substring(1, idList.length() - 1).replace(", ", ",");
```

Comment: It can also be like this - String csv = idList.substring(1, (idList.length() - 1));

Comment: It depends if you want to keep the spaces after the commas or not.

Answer (score 104):

```
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;

Joiner.on(",").join(ids);
```

or you can use **StringUtils**:

```
   public static String join(Object[] array,
                              char separator)

   public static String join(Iterable<?> iterator,
                              char separator)
```

*Joins the elements of the provided array/iterable into a single String containing the provided list of elements.*

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Comment: +1 - Joiner works with an iterable or object array, and can do things like skipping nulls in the input.

Comment: `StringUtils.join` also accepts `Collection` and `Iterator` object.

Answer (score 65):

**If you want to convert list into the CSV format .........**

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
ids.add("1");
ids.add("2");
ids.add("3");
ids.add("4");

// CSV format
String csv = ids.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
            .replace(", ", ",");

// CSV format surrounded by single quote 
// Useful for SQL IN QUERY

String csvWithQuote = ids.toString().replace("[", "'").replace("]", "'")
            .replace(", ", "','");
```

Comment: Very nice, without any third party library, clever!

Comment: Only works if the strings in the list don't contain any of `[,]`.

Comment: And hope that java won't change the to string of list. 
It's a risky way wouldn't use this in a productive system.

Answer (score 55):

The quickest way is

```
StringUtils.join(ids, ",");
```

Comment: Don't forget to import `StringUtils`: `import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`
commons-lang3 is a great library for String related methods.

Comment: StringUtils for the win!

Comment: [Apache Commons Lang 3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)'s `StringUtils.join(*)` methods are deprecated in favour of [Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/).

Answer (score 26):

The following:

```
String joinedString = ids.toString()
```

will give you a comma delimited list. [See docs for details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--).

You will need to do some post-processing to remove the square brackets, but nothing too tricky.

Answer (score 18):

One Liner (**pure Java**)

```
list.toString().replace(", ", ",").replaceAll("[\\[.\\]]", "");
```

Comment: what is the first replaceAll doing? why are we replacing replacing "," with "," ?

Comment: this will remove spaces from the strings themselves, so ["hello world"] will become "helloworld"

Comment: @marmor, now it should work. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

**Join / concat** & **Split** functions on **ArrayList**:

To **Join /concat** all elements of arraylist with **comma** ("**,**") to String.

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
ids.add("1");
ids.add("2");
ids.add("3");
ids.add("4");
String allIds = TextUtils.join(",", ids);
Log.i("Result", allIds);
```

To **split** all elements of String to arraylist  with **comma** ("**,**").

```
String allIds = "1,2,3,4";
String[] allIdsArray = TextUtils.split(allIds, ",");
ArrayList<String> idsList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(allIdsArray));
for(String element : idsList){
    Log.i("Result", element);
}
```

**Done**

Comment: Please refer the package. This is android.text.TextUtils ?

Answer (score 10):

I am having ArrayList of String, which I need to convert to comma separated list, without space. The ArrayList toString() method adds square brackets, comma and space. I tried the Regular Expression method as under.

```
List<String> myProductList = new ArrayList<String>();
myProductList.add("sanjay");
myProductList.add("sameer");
myProductList.add("anand");
Log.d("TEST1", myProductList.toString());     // "[sanjay, sameer, anand]"
String patternString = myProductList.toString().replaceAll("[\\s\\[\\]]", "");
Log.d("TEST", patternString);                 // "sanjay,sameer,anand"
```

Please comment for more better efficient logic.
( The code is for Android / Java )

Thankx.

Answer (score 5):

Java 8 solution if it's not a collection of strings:

```
{Any collection}.stream()
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)
    .toString()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use below code if object has attibutes under it.

```
String getCommonSeperatedString(List<ActionObject> actionObjects) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (ActionObject actionObject : actionObjects){
        sb.append(actionObject.Id).append(",");
    }
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf(","));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) (formerly GS Collections), you can use the `makeString()` method.

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
ids.add("1");
ids.add("2");
ids.add("3");
ids.add("4");

Assert.assertEquals("1,2,3,4", ListAdapter.adapt(ids).makeString(","));
```

If you can convert your `ArrayList` to a `FastList`, you can get rid of the adapter.

```
Assert.assertEquals("1,2,3,4", FastList.newListWith(1, 2, 3, 4).makeString(","));
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse collections.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code given below to convert a List into a comma separated string without iterating List explicitly for that you have to make a list and add item in it than convert it into a comma separated string

Output of this code will be: Veeru,Nikhil,Ashish,Paritosh

instead of output of list [Veeru,Nikhil,Ashish,Paritosh]

```
String List_name;
List<String> myNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
myNameList.add("Veeru");
myNameList.add("Nikhil");
myNameList.add("Ashish");
myNameList.add("Paritosh");

List_name = myNameList.toString().replace("[", "")
                    .replace("]", "").replace(", ", ",");
```