# How to format a string with a variable number of arguments

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

Lets say I have a method which returns a list with a random number of random numbers - we will call that method `List<Integer> getRandomNumberOfRandomNumbers();`

```
System.out.println(String.format("Here are the random numbers: %s", getRandomNumberOfRandomNumbers()));
```

I know this won't work but how can I achieve this effect?

### Example Output

```
Here are the random numbers:

1 4 2 4

Here are the random numbers:

2 43 323 434 3423 54
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/63258/7098259

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easiest to just make getRandomNumberOfRandomNumbers return all of the numbers in a single String. Or you could do it all inline, like this:

```
getRandomNumberOfRandomNumbers().stream()
    .map(Object::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Answer (score 3):

For example, if we have a `List` of `Integers` as below:

```
List<Integer> var = new ArrayList<>();
var.add(1);
var.add(4);
var.add(2);
var.add(4);
```

Then to print the `List` in your desired way, you can follow this:

```
System.out.println(String.format("Here are the random numbers:%n%n%s",
                             var.toString().replaceAll("[,\\[,\\]]", "")));
```

This outputs:

```
Here are the random numbers:

1 4 2 4
```

Here `var` is the `list` your function `getRandomNumberOfRandomNumbers()` is returning and we are converting it to String using `var.toString()` but it returns `[1, 4, 2, 4]`. So, we need to remove `[`, `]` and `,`. I used regular expression to replace them with an empty character. This is actually simple and easy way but not sure whether it is an efficient way!! Whenever i need to convert a `Colletion` to `String`, i use `toString()` method and then do some trick with regular expression to get my desired form of representation.

**Update**: After surfing web, i found few alternatives. (**Preferred** over my previous answer using `List.toString()`)

- [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) : a relevant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63258/5352399) in SO

For example, in your case, you can do:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
for (Integer i : var) {
    sj.add(String.valueOf(i));
}
System.out.println(sj.toString());
```

You can do the same with the following two alternatives.

- [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) : a relevant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15815631/5352399) in SO
- [String.Join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) : requires [CharSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html)

Comment: it's bad to rely on the implementation of the List's toString like that. It may change depending on implementation. Also you should use `%n` not `\n`

Comment: is there any reason to prefer `%n` over `\n`? and when you said List's `toString()` can be changed, did you mean if java API changes? i guess the probability is pretty low and yes off course, we can change our code if someday `toString()` returns different string representation.

Comment: `%n` is OS independant.

Comment: @WasiAhmad when you are working on a large team with different areas of responsibility, you cannot rely on List returned by someone else's method to always remain an ArrayList. In the future they may use a custom version of AbstractList that overrides the default toString. Assumptions like this are a bad habit.

Comment: @PatrickParker i agree with you. i didn't think in that way. i appreciate your explanation and frankly speaking after your comment, i have updated my answer with more reasonable ways. if you have given me downvote for that reason, i urge you to reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is iterating through the list and adding the values to a string builder before printing it out

like so:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(Integer number : getRandomNumberOfRandomNumbers())
    stringBuilder.append(number + " ");
System.out.println("Here are the random numbers: " + stringBuilder.toString().trim());
```