# How I can get the result of the list as string or comma separated?

Tags: java, string, list

I have this code below. I want to get the result as string and as one element of list from string type. First method is searching method that gives me list of emails. I want these emails as one element comma separated from string type.

```java
public List<UserDto> getEmail() {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet searchResultSet = null;
    try {
        connection = getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "SELECT LISTAGG(USER.U_EMAIL, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY USER.U_EMAIL) AS Emails FROM USER USER WHERE USER.U_SEQ IN ('1','560') GROUP BY USER.U_EMAIL");
        searchResultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        return getEmail(searchResultSet);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            preparedStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

private List<UserDto> getEmail(ResultSet searchResultSet) throws SQLException {
    List<UserDto> result = new ArrayList<UserDto>();
    UserDto userDto = null;
    while (searchResultSet.next()) {
        userDto = new UserDto();
        userDto.setEmailAddress(searchResultSet.getString(1));
        result.add(userDto);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Query is working fine.

Then second method just sending an email.

```java
Delegate delegate = new Delegate();
    List<UserDto> users = iimDelegate.getEmail();
    delegate.sendNotification("****", "****", users, "", "",
                   "", body);
```

Please note that `sendNotification` method accept the emails only from string type which is why we have to get the result as one element from string type.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please explain more understandable.

Comment: You want the e-mail addresses of all users **joined** into one comma-separated string?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it yourself, it is not much work:

```
String getUserEmails(List<UserDto> users) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (UserDto user: users) {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        } else {
            sb.append("; ");
        }
        sb.append(user.setEmailAddress());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

If you had a List, you could even do something like

```
String.join("; ", users);
```

(see [Best way to convert list to comma separated string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815587/best-way-to-convert-list-to-comma-separated-string-in-java))