# Android: Store ArrayList into sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

I have been banging my head against the wall for a while and I can't figure out how I could store an ArrayList into a sqlite column. I was thing it would work like the following:

Storing into database:

```
ArrayList -> String
String -> Sqlite column

Retrieving:

Sqlite column data -> ArrayList
```

However, I am unsure on how to accomplish this? Any guidance or advice?

Comment: an arraylist is a list of things, not a single item, so unless you store it as a delimited string then maybe creating a one to many relationship would be better.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142285/saving-arraylist-in-sqlite-database-in-android

Answer (score 0):

[Convert List to comma (whatever) delimited String.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850753/how-to-convert-a-liststring-into-a-comma-separated-string-without-iterating-li)

[Convert delimited String to List.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488643/java-how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-arraylist)

You will need a large text column though. You never know how large these lists can get. As @Java1 suggested, maybe a master/detail would be better for this?