# Convert int[] to comma-separated string

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

How can I convert `int[]` to comma-separated String in Java?

```
int[] intArray = {234, 808, 342};
```

Result I want:

```
"234, 808, 342"
```

Here are very similar reference question but none of those solution provide a result, exact I need.

- [How to convert an int array to String with toString method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904911/how-to-convert-an-int-array-to-string-with-tostring-method-in-java)
- [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)
- [How to convert a List<String> into a comma separated string without iterating List explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850753/how-to-convert-a-liststring-into-a-comma-separated-string-without-iterating-li)

What I've tried so far,

```
String commaSeparatedUserIds = Arrays.toString(intArray); // result: "[234, 808, 342]"
String commaSeparatedUserIds = Arrays.toString(intArray).replaceAll("\\[|\\]|,|\\s", ""); // result: "234808342"
String commaSeparatedUserIds = intArray.toString();  // garbage result
```

Comment: `Arrays.toString(intArray)` and simply drop the last and first character, dont do regex stuff.

Comment: @luk2302 - Can you provide me exact solution. I'm novice for `Java`. I've expertise in `iOS` only

Comment: String s = Arrays.toString(intArray);
        s = s.substring(1,s.length()-1);
should solve your problem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a stream version which is functionally equivalent to khelwood's, yet uses different methods.

They both create an `IntStream`, map each `int` to a `String` and join those with commas.

They should be pretty identical in performance too, although *technically* I'm calling `Integer.toString(int)` directly whereas he's calling `String.valueOf(int)` which delegates to it. On the other hand I'm calling `IntStream.of()` which delegates to `Arrays.stream(int[])`, so it's a tie.

```
String result = IntStream.of(intArray)
                         .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                         .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Comment: This works but creates potentially a lot of intermediate `String` objects, if the array is long. I'll add an answer for the fast (old-school) way of doing it.

Answer (score 13):

This should do

```
String arrAsStr = Arrays.toString(intArray).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");
```

After Arrays toString, replacing the `[]` gives you the desired output.

Answer (score 6):

```
        int[] intArray = {234, 808, 342, 564};
        String s = Arrays.toString(intArray);
        s = s.substring(1,s.length()-1);
```

This should work. basic idea is to get sub string from `Arrays.toString()` excluding first and last character

If want quotation in result, replace last line with:

```
s = "\"" + s.substring(1,s.length()-1) + "\"";
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to convert the ints to strings, and join them with commas. You can do this with streams.

```
int[] intArray = {234, 808, 342};
String s = Arrays.stream(intArray)
                 .mapToObj(String::valueOf) // convert each int to a string
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")); // join them with ", "
```

Result:

```
"234, 808, 342"
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and editor showing warning to `Set project compiler compliance settings to 1.8` and `Set project JRE build path entry to 'JavaSE-1.8'`. While I have already set `JRE System Library [Java SE 1.8]` for `Java Build Path` for my project

Comment: @Krunal Check for your compiler version too ?

Answer (score 2):

This is the pattern I always use for separator-joining. It's a pain to write this boilerplate every time, but it's much more efficient (in terms of both memory and processing time) than the newfangled `Stream` solutions that others have posted.

```
public static String toString(int[] arr) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            buf.append(", ");
        }
        buf.append(arr[i]);
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: @Kayaman obviously it's longer than your version, and also obviously, most of the time performance doesn't matter much. But if you're dealing with files gigabytes in size (which I routinely do), you need something dramatically less wasteful on resources than your solution -- which is why I provided this as an alternative. You don't believe me about how much faster my solution is than yours? Benchmark it. I have benchmarked similar things many times before, and I was horrified at how much performance I was losing through using the new stream API and the lambda system.

Comment: This is not low-level performance stuff. We're talking about an order of magnitude of difference in performance. As I said I have benchmarked this several times. I don't have the time or the motivation to do that again just to prove the point to you.