# Separate chars in Array list by a comma java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The most sophisticated way for creating comma-separated Strings from a Collection/Array/List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205555/the-most-sophisticated-way-for-creating-comma-separated-strings-from-a-collectio)

All the chars should be separated by a comma except for the last char.
Example output: "Previous characters guessed: a, b, c, x" or "Previous characters guessed: a"

Heres what I have:

```
ArrayList<Character> charsGuessed = new ArrayList<Character>();

//takes in char guess from user
char guess=getCharacterGuess(in);

//adds char guessed to array
charsGuessed.add(guess);

int size=charsGuessed.size();
System.out.print("Previous characters guessed: ");

for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
   if(i<=size-1)
   {
      System.out.print(charsGuessed.get(i) + " ");
   }
   else
   {
      System.out.print("," + " " + charsGuessed.get(i));
   }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205555/the-most-sophisticated-way-for-creating-comma-separated-strings-from-a-collectio might help

Comment: You should improve details of your questions. So one line ... really?

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringBuilder` better:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
    builder.append(charsGuessed.get(i));
    if (i < arraySize - 1){
        builder.append(", ");
    }
}
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

[bellum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13673232/697449) covered the use of `StringBuilder` well. If you happen to be using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), you can use [`Joiner`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html):

```
String charsGuessedConcat = Joiner.on(", ").join(charsGuessed);
System.out.print("Previous characters guessed: " + charsGuessedConcat);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very straightforward. Basically, you want to print/append a comma after every character in the list except for the last one.

Example:

```
private static void printGuessedCharacters(List<Character> chars) {
    System.out.print("Characters guessed: ");

    if(chars.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("none.");
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < chars.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(chars.get(i));

        if(i < chars.size() - 1) { // If it's not the last char in list.
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

On a side note, if you want a collection that only holds unique values, you can look into using a `HashSet` rather than an `ArrayList`. This will prevent your program from printing out the same character more than once.