# Is there an easier way to collect strings from a collection of objects?

Tags: java, android, collections

I have a collection of `Ingredient` objects for which I'd like get all their names (via `getName()`) and join them into a comma-delimited string.  Currently my code looks like this:

```
public static String getIngredientList(Collection<Ingredient> ingredients) {
    final Iterator<Ingredient> iterator = ingredients.iterator();
    final String[] names = new String[ingredients.size()];

    for (int i = 0; iterator.hasNext(); i++) {
        names[i] = iterator.next().getName();
    }

    return TextUtils.join(", ", names);
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a more concise way to collect all the names into a `String[]` object.  If this were Ruby, for example, it'd be easy to pull off a short one-liner to do exactly what I need:

```
ingredients.map(&:name).join(', ')
```

Comment: @323go probably Ingredients will have more than a field

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205555/the-most-sophisticated-way-for-creating-comma-separated-strings-from-a-collectio

Comment: This would be a tricky and not a very good way but you can implement toString of `Ingredient` which will return only value of name. And then you can simply use `TextUtils.join(", ",ingredients.toArray())`

Comment: Java 8 will finally allow a ruby-esque way of solving this (either via a simple Lambda or with a method handle directly).

Comment: a simple `ingredients.stream().map(Ingredient::getName).collect(joining(",  " );` would do now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) you can write the following using JDK 5 - 7:

```
MutableList<Ingredient> ingredients =
        Lists.mutable.with(
                new Ingredient("Flour"),
                new Ingredient("Sugar"),
                new Ingredient("Eggs"),
                new Ingredient("Milk"));
MutableList<String> ingredientNames = ingredients.collect(new Function<Ingredient, String>()
{
    public String valueOf(Ingredient ingredient)
    {
        return ingredient.getName();
    }
});
String delimitedNames = ingredientNames.makeString(", ");
Assert.assertEquals("Flour, Sugar, Eggs, Milk", delimitedNames);
```

Using Java 8 with support for lambdas and method references you can compress it down to the following:

```
MutableList<Ingredient> ingredients =
        Lists.mutable.with(
                new Ingredient("Flour"),
                new Ingredient("Sugar"),
                new Ingredient("Eggs"),
                new Ingredient("Milk"));
String delimitedNames =
        ingredients.collect(Ingredient::getName).makeString(", ");
Assert.assertEquals("Flour, Sugar, Eggs, Milk", delimitedNames);
```

In this example, using the overloaded form of makeString() without parameters will result in the same string, as makeString() calls makeString(“, “).

```
String delimitedNames =
        ingredients.collect(Ingredient::getName).makeString();
Assert.assertEquals("Flour, Sugar, Eggs, Milk", delimitedNames);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a `StringBuilder` in the first place?
The relevant part of the code:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for(Ingredient ingredient: ingredients) {
    b.append(ingredient.getName() + ", ");
}
return b.toString();
```

Of course you have to remove the last ", " appended which can be done with using the `substring` method or not appending the last one.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for(String string : collectionOfStrings) {
    result.append(string);
    result.append(",");
}
return result.length() > 0 ? result.substring(0, result.length() - 1): "";
```

see the duplicate post:
[The most sophisticated way for creating comma-separated Strings from a Collection/Array/List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205555/the-most-sophisticated-way-for-creating-comma-separated-strings-from-a-collectio)