# How to get rid of ", " in the end of my print?

Tags: java, stack

So I created a toString method that changes my stack into a string type. I want my output to be [A, B, C] but in my method it returns an extra ", " in the end which I do not want it to do. How do I make it so that my method does not put the comma space after the last element.

Here's my code:

```
public String toString(){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
    Node<E> temp = topOfStack;
    while (temp != null) {
        sb.append(temp.data).append(", ");
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    return sb.append("]").toString();

}
```

Here's my test:

```
public void testToString() {

    assertEquals("[A, B, C]", stack.toString());

}
```

Here's the output on my toString method:

[A, B, C, ]

Comment: Are you aware of the `join` method of the Apache `StringUtils` class?  It could be useful in a case like this.

Comment: no i'm not, haven't learned anything like that

Comment: possible duplicate of [The most sophisticated way for creating comma-separated Strings from a Collection/Array/List?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205555/the-most-sophisticated-way-for-creating-comma-separated-strings-from-a-collectio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there can be many more way to do that .. following is just one of them.

```
while (temp != null) {
        sb.append(temp.data);
        temp = temp.next;
        if(temp != null)
           sb.append(",");
    }
```

Comment: @user3321427 Please accept this answer to reward it.+1

Answer (score 1):

This is a good logic exercise so I'll just give hints. Instead of unconditionally adding the comma, you only want to add it in certain cases. For example:

```
A           //No comma since string was empty before adding A
A, B        //Hint: the comma is coming before the B!
A, B, C     //Same hint
```

So you only want to include the comma if the string you're adding to is *not* empty (as is the case when you add the B and C, but not A). How can you program that?

And yes, I'm deliberately leaving the `[ ]` characters out; implement the logic I specified above first, and then it's trivial to put the brackets in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sb.substring(0,sb.length()-1);

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick I like in these cases is to check if string builder is not empty and prepend delimeter. Pseudocode:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(foo.hasNext()) {
    if (sb.length() > 0) sb.append(", ");

    sb.append(foo.bar()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing your return statement to something like this:

```
ln = sb.length();
return sb.substring(0,ln-1).append("]").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just updated your method:

```
public String toString(){

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
Node<E> temp = topOfStack;
while (temp != null) {
    if(sb.length() > 1)
       sb.append(", ");
    sb.append(temp.data);
    temp = temp.next;
}
return sb.append("]").toString();
```

`}`

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
 public String toString(){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
    Node<E> temp = topOfStack;
    while (temp != null) {    
    sb.append(temp.data).append(temp.next == null ? "" : ", "); 
    temp = temp.next;
    }
    return sb.append("]").toString();

}
```